# Display value from script on my site

Tags: javascript, html

So, as one of my first projects, I tried to do a little lottery draw site, but I can't display the `winPercentage` variable from the `script.js` on the site. It just stays empty. Why?

The `script.js` part:

```
    var winPercentage = winCount / gameCount * 100;
    document.getElementById("winPercentageID").innerHTML = winPercentage;
```

The HTML part:

```
    Your Win Percentage is : <br>
    <span id = "winPercentageId"></span>
```

Comment: You did not correctly write the ID

Comment: `"winPercentageId" != "winPercentageID"` - Typo?  Also, do your other variables have values at the time that you calculate it?  Is the calculation happening before or after the element exists on the page?  Are there any errors on the browser's debugging console?

Answer (score 1):

Your id `winPercentageID` does not match `winPercentageId` (uppercase "ID" vs "Id")

Comment: Damn, was looking at the code for some time, couldn't figure it out, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Win Percentage is : <br>
    <span id = "winPercentageId"></span>
```

There is a typo problem I think:

> `winPercentageId` is in the `span` not same as `document.getElementById("winPercentageID")`

Just change that...

Comment: Damn, was looking at the code for some time, couldn't figure it out, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to do it with jQuery.

```
var winPercentage = winCount / gameCount * 100;
$("#winPercentageID").html(winPercentage)
```

Comment: because thats more easy to use.